# Custom Writable vs. concatenated String performance in Hadoop

Tags: java, performance, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm writing a MapReduce job in Hadoop where performance is very important and I have to decide how to transfer multiple values between my Mappers and Reducers (and possibly write them to disk for further job chaining)

In my case, I have a `Text`, followed by two `IntWritable`s in each value. My question is, should I output the value as concatenated Strings like `Word:Number:Number`, or should I implement a custom `Writable` that has 3 fields for optimal performance?

I'm interested in the trade-offs between serialization and casting/string splitting (even with a more performant library like the Guava splitter)